# error Trying to get property 'id_mascota' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with laravel wanting to redirect with the id of the pets table sends me the error message of Trying to get property 'id_mascota' of non-object.I already executed the query in mysql and it works fine.
Controller:

```
public function index(){

        $mascotas = DB::table('mascota as m') /*Propiedad*/
        ->join('cliente as c','m.id_cliente','=','c.id_cliente','left',false)
        ->join('cat_tipo_mascota as tm','m.id_tipo_mascota','=','tm.id_tipo_mascota','left',false)
        ->join('cat_razas as r','m.id_raza','=','r.id_raza','left',false)
        ->join('cat_sexo as s','m.id_sexo','=','s.Id_sexo','left',false)
        ->select('c.nombre as nCliente','m.id_cliente','tm.tipo_mascota',
            'm.id_tipo_mascota','r.nombre as nRaza','m.id_raza','s.sexo','m.id_sexo','m.fecha_nacimiento','m.peso','m.estatura'
            ,'m.nombre as nMascota','m.edad','m.caracteristicas','m.imagen','m.id_mascota')
        ->paginate(10);

        return view('mascotas.index',["mascotas"=>$mascotas);
    }
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('contenido')
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header card-header-info ">
        <h4 class="card-title ">Mascota</h4>
        <p class="card-category"> Listado de Madcotas</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-9">
            <div class="form-group">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-inspector"><button class="btn btn-info btn-block">Nueva Mascota</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal collapse" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-inspector">
            {{ Form::open(array('action'=>array('MascotaController@crear'),'method'=>'post')) }}
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title text-dark">Nuevo Cliente</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nuevo_jaula">Nombre</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="mascota_nombre" id="mascota_nombre" value=""  class="letrasModal form-control" required="true" />
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nuevo_jaula">Fecha Nacimiento</label>
                                    <input type="date" name="mascota_fecha" id="mascota_fecha" value=""  class="letrasModal form-control" required="true" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nuevo_jaula">Peso</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="mascota_peso" id="mascota_peso" value=""  class="letrasModal form-control" required="true" />
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nuevo_jaula">Estatura</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="mascota_estatura" id="mascota_estatura" value=""  class="letrasModal form-control" required="true" />
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nuevo_jaula">Edad</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="mascota_edad" id="mascota_edad" value=""  class="letrasModal form-control" required="true" />
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <label for="">Dueño</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="mascota_cliente" name="mascota_cliente">
                                  @foreach ($clientes as $cliente)
                                    <option  value="{{ $cliente->id_cliente }}">{{ $cliente->nombre }}</option>
                                  @endforeach
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <label for="">Tipo de mascota</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="mascota_tipo" name="mascota_tipo">
                                  @foreach ($tipo_mascota as $tipomascota)
                                    <option  value="{{ $tipomascota->id_tipo_mascota }}">{{ $tipomascota->tipo_mascota }}</option>
                                  @endforeach
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <label for="">Raza</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="mascota_raza" name="mascota_raza">
                                  @foreach ($raza as $razas)
                                    <option  value="{{ $razas->id_raza }}">{{ $razas->nombre }}</option>
                                  @endforeach
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <label for="">Sexo</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="mascota_sexo" name="mascota_sexo">
                                  @foreach ($sexo as $sexos)
                                    <option  value="{{ $sexos->Id_sexo }}">{{ $sexos->sexo }}</option>
                                  @endforeach
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nuevo_jaula">Caracteristicas</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="mascota_caracteristicas" id="mascota_caracteristicas" value=""  class="letrasModal form-control" required="true" />
                                </div>
                            </div>          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ Form::close()}}

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <th>
                ID
              </th>
              <th>
                Nombre
              </th>
              <th>
                Dueño
              </th>
              <th>
                Edad
              </th>
              <th>
                Raza
              </th>
              <th>
                Sexo
              </th>
              @auth
              @if (auth()->user()->rol == 'Admin')
              <th>
                Acciones
              </th>
              @endif
              @endauth
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach ($mascotas as $mascota)         
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a class="text-dark" href="{{URL::action('MascotaController@show', $mascota->id_mascota)}}" >
                  {{ $mascota->id_mascota}}</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="text-dark" href="{{URL::action('MascotaController@show', $mascota->id_mascota)}}" >
                  {{ $mascota->nMascota}}</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="text-dark" href="{{URL::action('MascotaController@show', $mascota->id_mascota)}}" >
                  {{ $mascota->nCliente}}</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="text-dark" href="{{URL::action('MascotaController@show', $mascota->id_mascota)}}" >
                  {{ $mascota->edad}}</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="text-dark" href="{{URL::action('MascotaController@show', $mascota->id_mascota)}}" >
                  {{ $mascota->nRaza}}</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="text-dark" href="{{URL::action('MascotaController@show', $mascota->id_mascota)}}" >
                  {{ $mascota->sexo}}</a>
                </td>
                @auth
                @if (auth()->user()->rol == 'Admin')
                <td>
                  <a href="{{URL::action('MascotaController@destroy', $mascota->id_mascota)}}"  style="width: 30%;"><button class="btn btn-danger" style="font-size: 12px; margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button></a>                
                </td>
                @endif
                @endauth
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        {{$mascotas->render()}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@push('scripts')
@endpush  
@endsection
```

Error message:
[image]

I appreciate your comments and your help in solving this problem.

Using the dd to see the array results sends me these values:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#953 ▼
  #total: 1
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#945 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => {#943 ▼
        +"id_mascota": 1
        +"nCliente": "Paola"
        +"id_cliente": 6
        +"tipo_mascota": "Perro"
        +"id_tipo_mascota": 1
        +"nRaza": "Gato montes"
        +"id_raza": 1
        +"sexo": "Macho"
        +"id_sexo": 1
        +"fecha_nacimiento": "2019-07-02"
        +"peso": "21.00"
        +"estatura": "432.00"
        +"nMascota": "chilisquis"
        +"edad": 32
        +"caracteristicas": "Perro negro con manchas blancas"
        +"imagen": null
      }
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/mascotas"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▼
    "path" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/mascotas"
    "pageName" => "page"
  ]
}
```

Comment: try to use `dd($yourvariable);` in controller to see if your variable is not empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: you get Collection and that's the problem

Comment: as @Jovs  said try `dd($mascota)`  if you are getting data or not... also if it return null you can wrap it will `?? (NULLCOALESCE)` ex: `$mascota->id_mascota ?? 'empty'`

Comment: If you need to get a single row then use ->first() instead of ->get() if its a multiple data then use @foreach for the collection

Comment: try commenting line 151..?

Comment: can give the image of result of `dd()`

Comment: I can not add a dd image but I show you the result that I throw